# How to construct derived class with existing base class object

Tags: java, multithreading, subclass, superclass

i need to construct class for example Apple or Strawberry from existing Fruit object.

This is my Fruit class:

```
public class Fruit {
    int somevariable;
    Thread somethread;

    public Fruit(int somevariable) {
        this.somevariable = somevariable;

        this.somethread = new Thread() {
            public void run() { /* Something here */ }
        }

        this.somethread.start();
    }

    public Fruit(Fruit fruit) {
        this.somevariable = fruit.somevariable;
        this.somethread = fruit.somethread;
    }
}
```

And this is my Apple and Strawberry class:

```
public class Apple extends Fruit {
    public Apple(Fruit fruit) {
        super(fruit);
    }
}

public class Strawberry extends Fruit {
    public Strawberry(Fruit fruit) {
        super(fruit);
    }
}
```

And i have HashMap like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Fruit> fruits = new HashMap<>();
```

At first, I am adding fruits like this:
(All I know is that this is the fruit at the moment. I can't add an apple or a strawberry immediately.)

```
fruits.put(17, new Fruit(4));
fruits.put(24, new Fruit(8));
fruits.put(95, new Fruit(12));
```

And when I find out what kind of fruit it is, I need to replace the fruit object with an apple or a strawberry (with same fruit object as super object). Of course without stopping somethread.

And this is how I solve it:

```
fruits.replace(17, new Strawberry(fruits.get(17)));
fruits.replace(24, new Apple(fruits.get(24)));
fruits.replace(95, new Strawberry(fruits.get(95)));
```

My questions is:

Can this be made easier? Is my solution correct?

And one more question, if I have functions in a strawberry that are often called from other Threads, how to make sure there is no problem during hashmap value replacement?

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: If you’re using a `HashMap` for multithreaded code you’re already so far off the correct path that everything else is probably also questionable. Given that your `Fruit` objects control your `Thread` instances and these are themselves replaced by I can only presume themselves (i.e. their own threads); I don’t know how to answer this question.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the purpose/goal of the code you have here? I mean, if that can be defined then you might get the suited answer.

Comment: I'm writing a server for electric car chargers. The problem came when we decided to add more types of devices, not just chargers. When a device connects, I put it into the HashMap as a Device. And when I received a message telling you about a device type, then I need to construct it as Charger for example and keep Device inside it as super class. The code I wrote here is just an example... Really thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Prefer composition to inheritance.* Subclassing a concrete class (except `Object` although that being concrete is sort of kind of being "deprecated" at the moment) isn't usually great.

`Fruit` should have a `FruitType` (or better name). Delegate as necessary.

Also note, in the original code, that the `Runnable` (**Edit:** `Thread` with naught overridden `run`) will have been created in the context of the original `Fruit` instance. Also also, the thread will initially see a `Fruit` that is not guaranteed to be fully initialised.

Answer (score 0):

As for concurrent modification use Collections.synchronizedMap or ConcurrentHashMap.

As for making is easier could you specify what you want to make easier? To not have to write constructor?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "*Can this be made easier? Is my solution correct?*"

Yes. You don't have to do `replace` at all here since objects you put in the map are of type `Fruit` just cast it when you need to operate on it.

You can also check like `obj instanceof Fruit` if you would prefer to be more specific.

Furthermore, your code does not look safe at all as @miszcz2137 mentioned also, *concurrent modification* is imminent.

Comment: Can I solve concurrent modifications and do it correctly by using ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap?